# Can we do something to these repeated code at each function?

Tags: asp.net

Can we do something to these repeated code at each function? Like calling same work from one function to all. I am new to this asp.net and classes stuff. any idea would be appreciated.

```
connection.Open(); //.........these codes from 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
connection.Close();
return dataTable; //.........to here

public class attendance {

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnection"].ConnectionString);

    //<employee>
    public DataTable employeeList() {

        string query = "select * from view_emp_info";
        connection.Open(); //.........these codes from here 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        connection.Close();
        return dataTable; //.........to here
    }
    //</employee>

    //<promotion>
    public DataTable promotionList() {

        string query = "select * from tbl_emp_promotion_detail order by TDate DESC";
        connection.Open(); //.........these codes from here 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        connection.Close();
        return dataTable; //.........to here
    }   
}
```

Comment: Well, you are almost there. You identified the duplicate code. The only thing that's different is the `query` which you can pass as an argument to a function.

Comment: You're using DataTable, but working with dedicated classes would be easier and more efficient. You can use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), which makes going from a SQL query to strongly typed objects easy.

Answer (score 2):

Spoiler:

```
public class Attendance { // Classes should start with a capital

    private readonly string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnection"].ConnectionString;

    //<employee>
    public DataTable GetEmployeeList() { // Somewhat more clear

        string query = "select * from view_emp_info"; // Select * is not recommended. You know the columns. If the schema changes and this fails, you'll at least know why on the spot.
        return FetchTable(query);
    }
    //</employee>

    //<promotion>
    public DataTable GetPromotionList() { // again, clear method names

        string query = "select * from tbl_emp_promotion_detail order by TDate DESC";
        return FetchTable(query);
    }  

    private DataTable FetchTable(string query)
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) ) throw new ArgumentException();
        DataTable dataTable = null;
        // make a new connection, auto-close and dispose to avoid trouble
        // _unless_ you are using ConnectionPooling
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```